# Java convert a negative/positive string number into negative/pozitive double

Tags: java, string, double

Does anyone know how to convert the string value type `-4,5` or `5,4` into a double `-4.5` or `5.4`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First replace , with . and then use following function -

```
 Double.valueOf("-4.5");
```

and

```
Double.valueOf("5.4");
```

Comment: You missed the issue with the decimal separator.

Comment: Thank you, I've been able to use your option after changing the string decimal separator from `,` to `.` returned from PHP code.

Comment: @AndreiStalbe Why would you accept this answer, when Martijn shows the right way below!

Answer (score 8):

<del>Just use `Double.parseDouble(Locale, String)`;</del> Woops, I was confused...

You should use [java.text.NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
Number number = format.parse("-4,5");
double d = number.doubleValue();
```

For example, in Belgium or France we use a `,` as decimal separator. That is why it works.